# sublime text (3200) not allowing git commit ,how to resolve sublime text git commit issue?

Tags: command-line, 18.04, git, sublime-text

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 ,I have removed previous version of sublime text through Ubuntu Software and then installed it through sublime text's official documentation given [Here](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/linux_repositories.html) .

After that Whenever I am trying to `git commit` it gives the following message and does nothing .

```
git commit
hint: Waiting for your editor to close the file... 
'/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl' 
-n -w: 1: '/Applications/Sublime Text 
2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl' -n -w: 
/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl: 
not found
error: There was a problem with the editor ''/Applications/Sublime 
Text 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl' -n -w'.
Please supply the message using either -m or -F option.
```

I want to understand what exactly this issue is and how to resolve it .my current installed version of sublime text is build 3200 . Kindly suggest a way to resolve this issue ,thank you !

Comment: @dessert When I gave command 'git commit -m "Initial commit" ' it didn't create any problem and gave following output 
'git commit -m "Initial commit"
[master (root-commit) 95d53e5] Initial commit
 3 files changed, 14 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 css/app.css
 create mode 100644 index.html
 create mode 100644 js/app.js
'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If an `editor` is set in the git config `git commit` called without `-m` or `-F` will try to open this editor for you to provide a commit message, which is failing in your case. You can either only commit providing a commit message

```
git commit -m "my commit message"
```

or change the configuration, e.g. remove the editor lines with

```
git config --unset-all core.editor
```

or correct the setting with:

```
git config --global core.editor "subl -n -w"
```

Further reading:

- [How can I fix git commit error “Waiting for your editor to close the file…” with VS Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52195877/6164712)
- [Associating text editors with Git](https://help.github.com/en/articles/associating-text-editors-with-git)